# SQL Server: unable to copy database

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to create a dev database so I don't create triggers and such on the production database. I use the right click -> Taks -> Copy, followed the wizard and the process starts.

After maybe a minute, it stops and says Error.

The Event Viewer says this:

```
Package "ShellPackage" failed.

Event Name: OnError
 Message: ERROR : errorCode=-1073548784 description=Executing the query "CREATE VIEW [dbo].[VIEWNAME]
AS
SEL..." failed with the following error: "Invalid column name 'C_27'.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.
helpFile= helpContext=0 idofInterfaceWithError={C81DFC5A-3B22-4DA3-BD3B-10BF861A7F9C}
StackTrace:   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Dts.DtsTransferProvider.ExecuteTransfer()
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Transfer.TransferData()
Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.TransferObjectsTask.TransferObjectsTask.TransferDatabasesUsingSMOTransfer()
Operator: DOMAIN\administrator
 Source Name: SERVER_SERVER_Transfer Objects Task
 Source ID: {47D1A40A-A6CF-4A5C-897E-80CB9C1D6151}
 Execution ID: {3E979DF7-C5DC-4583-8613-CB9AC9153D56}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Does `CREATE VIEW [dbo].[VIEWNAME]` has `C_27` column ? Why dont you just do a backup / restore and then at the end drop all the triggers using `select 'drop trigger ' + name + + char(10) + ' go'  from sysobjects where type ='Tr'`

Comment: Why don't you just BACKUP/RESTORE?

Answer (score 3):

Best and most reliable way is to use [backup / restore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187048.aspx)

If your database is big and you are on sql server 2008 R2 and up, standard edition also has compression feature to allow you to compress your backups.

Dont forget to sync up users after the restore :-)

Answer (score 2):

Possible reason for the error: Was view `[dbo].[VIEWNAME]` created with `SELECT * FROM ...`? In this case an underlying table could've had a column removed, but the view definition (if it was not refreshed) would be none the wiser.
See [Selecting from a view shows the wrong set of columns](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/66080/selecting-from-a-view-shows-the-wrong-set-of-columns).

Concerning the approach to "copy" the DB - I agree with Kin and Aaron - better to use backup/restore.

Answer (score 0):

I actually did this first but it didn't work. I just found out what my mistake was though. I created a new database before I did the restore which failed because the backup contained a database other than the one I created

> "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The backup set holds a backup of a database other than the existing 'DB_DEV' database. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)"

But what I didn't know is I needed to create the new database by actually typing the name in the restore window without creating it first. I didn't know I could write in this field but I just gave it a shot and it worked!

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Dont use GUI for doing backup / restores. TSQL Commands are much powerful with lots of options that GUI does not offer.